# How to use a regular expression with apt-cache search to find all Wine versuons?

Tags: wine, regex

I am writing a script to install some things and I'm having trouble with a regular expression that I am using. I have the Wine repository in my apt sources (ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa) and I am using the following command:

```
apt-cache search wine[0-255].[0-255] | sort -nr
```

Now I was expecting to get 'wine1.7' at the top of the list, but it isn't even listed.

Instead if I run:

```
apt-cache search wine | sort -nr
```

I get a much longer list (obviously) and it contains 'wine1.7'. The list that fails does show a few correct items that match my regex, but not as many as without. These are a couple of examples:

- wine1.7-i386 - Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (32-bit support)
- wine1.7-amd64 - Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (64-bit support)
- wine1.5 - Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (dummy package)
- wine1.5-i386 - Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (32-bit support)
- wine1.5-dev - Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (64-bit support)

As you cane see 'wine1.5' is list, but not 'wine1.7'. Is there a better way to get this type of list?

Or better yet a simple way of finding the latest version from a list to install?

Comment: hmmm, [0-9] works, but not sure if that scales correctly, if the version goes to 10 or more for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how character classes work, the regex does not differentiate between `26` and `2` followed by `6`, so your character class is being interpreted as `1-2` or `5`. Also, the `.` means "match any character", not a literal `.`, I don't think the `apt` regex engine allows escaping, so you'd have to use a character class to match it (`[.]`). Finally, you need to have multiple occurrences of each number, so you need something like:

```
apt-cache search --names-only wine[0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*
```

The `--names-only` ensures that your regex is only matched agaist package names, not descriptions.

Comment: I think I'd use `apt-cache search --names-only "wine[0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*"`, as sometimes a 3.0 version is listed just "3" in the name. `+` means require at least one, `*` means zero or more.